# How convert table into string?

Tags: java, android, string

I want to convert table into one string:

```
int y []  =  {30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111, 123, 145};
```

Must be something as this:

```
String y = 30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111, 123, 145;
```

Far code:

```
public class GraphLoading extends Activity {
public static int [] y;
int Test;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loading);




int y []  =  {30, 34, 45, 57, 77, 89, 100, 111, 123, 145};



 }

public static int[] x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

}
```

I must convert that tablo into string then I can save it into SD card.

**Please can you paste full code? (I am amateur)**

Comment: Where did you get stuck exactly? Could you share your code so far?

Comment: hint: loop and String-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rely on the implementation of [`Arrays.toString`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
String y1 = Arrays.toString(y).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
```

Otherwise you can loop through your `int` array and append each element using a [`StringBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html).

Comment: I was looking for an answer like this one :-)

Comment: @user2908626 You're stuck with what exaclty?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        String str = "";
        for (int i : a) {
            str += i + ",";
        }
        str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
        System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not tested, but it should do the trick:

```
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String comma = "";

for (int i : y) {
    builder.append(comma);
    builder.append(i);
    comma = ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String str = Arrays.toString(y);
/*  Will return Array as a string as [30, 34, 45, ....]
*   Now use java  String library functions */

str = (str.replaceAll("}", ""));    
str = (str.replaceAll("{", ""));      

System.out.println(str);
```